# Error when trying to find ANY of int array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, concatenation, plpgsql

I'm currently working on a function in **PostgreSQL**, where it takes in an array of integers. Everything in the function is working as expected, however at one point in the function I do the following:

```
     EXECUTE 
     'INSERT INTO tmptable (user_id)
      SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM user_skills
      WHERE skill_values_id=ANY('||selected_skills||')';
```

My function is able to read the array at other points in the code, however this part throws the following error:

Procedure execution failed

```
 ERROR:  malformed array literal: "
    INSERT INTO tmptable (user_id)
    SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM user_skills
            WHERE skill_values_id=ANY("
```

---

And finally- there is a line at the bottom of the error message that says:

```
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

Any ideas how to get the any and integer array to play nice? I'm assuming it has something to do with the || concentration casting it to a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't concatenate values, use parameters instead:

```
 EXECUTE 
 'INSERT INTO tmptable (user_id)
  SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM user_skills
  WHERE skill_values_id=ANY($1)'
 using selected_skills;
```

More details in the manual:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: Awesome - I tried this previously and left out the
      
    using selected_skills;